# Overwriting a field of AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle

Tags: symfony, overwrite, admin-generator

I am trying to overwrite a field of the [AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle](https://github.com/cedriclombardot/AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle) and want to append a link to a certain field. That works quite well following the [documentation](http://symfony2admingenerator.org/documentation/form.html#overwrite-the-rendering-of-a-field):

```
{% extends_admingenerated "MyMainBundle:PageEdit:index.html.twig" %}
{% block form_status %}
    {{  parent() }}
    <a href="{{ path("_admin_preview", {'id': 8, '_format': 'pdf'}) }}">Preview</a>
{% endblock %}
```

What I would need to do now, is to get the real id of my page instead of the static 8, but i could not figure out, what the object is called inside the twig template. Any ideas?

**Update:**
In my case, as I only need the ID of my page, I can use app.request.attributes.get('pk') to get it in twig. Would be interesting how to get other values tough.

Comment: I started a topic at the AdminGenerator user group. https://groups.google.com/group/symfony2admingenerator/browse_thread/thread/772c37c1f73575a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
{% extends_admingenerated "MyMainBundle:PageEdit:index.html.twig" %}

{% block form_status %}
   {{  parent() }}
   <a href="{{ path("_admin_preview", {'id': Movie.Id, '_format': 'pdf'}) }}">Preview</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Cedric

Answer (score 0):

The [Documentation](http://symfony2admingenerator.org/documentation/list.html#overwrite-the-rendering-of-a-field) has been updated.

Thats ho it works:

```
{% extends_admingenerated "NamespaceYourBundle:List:index.html.twig" %}
{% block list_td_column_title %}
    <span style="font-weight:bold">{{ Movie.title }}</span>
{% endblock %}
```